# How to keep sprite on screen while increasing its width to screen width

Tags: unity, scale

I have been able to increase the width of a sprite to the width of the screen size, but the sprite exceeds the borders of the screen width to the right or left when I try expanding it when it's not at the center. How can I scale the sprite in such a way that it's width increases on both sides till it occupies the screen width without exceeding it's bounds, regardless of the sprite's initial position? Please see my code below:

```
bool isScaling = false;

IEnumerator scaleToX(SpriteRenderer spriteToScale, float newXValue, float byTime)
    {
       if (isScaling)
         {
           yield break;
         }
       isScaling = true;

       float counter = 0;
       float currentX = spriteToScale.transform.localScale.x;
       float yAxis = spriteToScale.transform.localScale.y;
       float ZAxis = spriteToScale.transform.localScale.z;

       Debug.Log(currentX);
       while (counter < byTime)
        {
          counter += Time.deltaTime;
          Vector3 tempVector = new Vector3(currentX, yAxis, ZAxis);
          tempVector.x = Mathf.Lerp(currentX, newXValue, counter / byTime);
          spriteToScale.transform.localScale = tempVector;
          yield return null;
        }

       isScaling = false;
  }
```

Comment: Set the pivot point at the center of your sprite.

Comment: @Jon How do I change the pivot and where should it be done?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't initially catch that you wanted the sprite to be able to be positioned anywhere before resizing.  I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually very simple.  All you need to do is determine the Camera Bounds, and then set the final resting position of your sprite, based on these bounds.

So, you would have the start position and size -- Determine the end position and size that you want, then lerp to it.  It is that easy.

Here is the script that will do this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Square : MonoBehaviour {

    Bounds CameraBounds;

    Vector2 EndScale;
    Vector2 EndPosition;
    Vector2 StartScale;
    Vector2 StartPosition;

    float Speed = 2;
    float SPEED = 2;

    void Start () {

        CameraBounds = GetCameraBounds ();

        StartPosition = this.transform.position;
        StartScale = this.transform.localScale;

        EndScale = CameraBounds.size;
        EndPosition = CameraBounds.center;
    }

    void Update () {

        Speed -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (Speed <= 0)
            Speed = 0;

        this.transform.localScale = Vector2.Lerp (EndScale, StartScale, Speed/SPEED);
        this.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp (EndPosition, StartPosition, Speed / SPEED); 
    }

    public Bounds GetCameraBounds()
    {
        float screenAspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
        float cameraHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
        Bounds bounds = new Bounds(Camera.main.transform.position,new Vector3(cameraHeight * screenAspect, cameraHeight, 0));
        return bounds;
    }

}
```

And this is an example of this script running on a 1:1 ratio sprite:
[image]

Comment: Actually I only wanted to increase the width, so I changed the `EndScale` to  `EndScale = new Vector2(CameraBounds.size.x, StartScale.y);` and `EndPosition` to `EndPosition = new Vector2(CameraBounds.center.x, StartPosition.y);` but it still exceeds the screen width

Comment: If you change the following in the Start() it should work:


`EndScale = new Vector2(CameraBounds.size.x, StartScale.y);`
`EndPosition = new Vector2 (CameraBounds.center.x, StartPosition.y);`

Comment: Hmm.. that is the same code - and it works for me.  Make sure your sprite is 1:1 with Unity Units.  So if your sprite is 32x32 -- set it to 32 unity units.

Comment: Or multiply the scale by your unit size to adjust accordingly.

Comment: From a Swift background the Unity units still get me a bit confused. I changed Pixels per unit to 64 to coincide with my test iPhone5 (1136x640) aspect ratio. The main camera size is still 5. Should this affect my result?

Comment: What is the size of the sprite you are trying to resize the transform?  In pixels?

Comment: the size is 121x51

Comment: Try changing the Units Per Pixel of that imported sprite to 51 -- it should work.

Comment: it's still exceeds the screen width

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it should be 121 as you are extending on the x-axis.  Anyways, the issue is your unit size.  You need to make sure that when you are resizing, that it matches up the units.  That is why I was saying you need to have a 1:1 ratio for the resize to understand where it is.

Comment: It's working, but my sprite is really, small. Is there another way around it?

Comment: Yes, you would have to adjust the scale factor if you do not want to set the pixel per unit size.  Instead, you would need to multiply your scale factor by the sprite ratio.   I have code for this somewhere... not sure where.

Comment: `PixelUnits = Sprite.rect.width / Sprite.bounds.size.x;`    Divide your scale factor by this value.

Comment: I just realised that basically all that has to be done  is `EndScale = new Vector2(worldScreenWidth / worldSpriteWidth, StartScale.y);` and `EndPosition = new Vector2 (cameraWidth/2, StartPosition.y);`. Now it's working. Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help